# Is there an $\varepsilon >0$ such that if $x<y$ then $x+\varepsilon <y $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $l<y\in\mathbb{R}$ Is there a $0<\varepsilon$ such that $\varepsilon + l<y$?

This came across in my attempt to prove that if there is a sequence in the reals such that $x_n\in(0,1]$ for all $n$ and $\lim x_n = l\notin(0,1]$ then $\lim x_n = 0$. My proof was by contradiction:

By hypothesis we know the limit exists. Now suppose $\lim x_n \neq 0$. Notice that $\lim x_n \ngeq 1$ since $\lim x_n \notin(0,1]$ and because $x_n\leq 1$ for all $n$.

Consider that $\lim x_n = l< 0$. This means that for all $0<\varepsilon$ there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ if $n>N$ then $-\varepsilon +l < x_n<\varepsilon +l$. I used the argument at the beginning to arrive to a contradiction (i am not sure if it is true). That is, there exists $0<\varepsilon$ such that $\varepsilon + l<0$. Hence $x_n<0$ but this is not possible since $x_n\in(0,1]$

So it must be that $l=0$

I'll appreciate any guidence. An other answer to the fact is welcomed, however I have more interest in the argument of the first line.

Comment: Take $$\varepsilon:=\frac{y-l}{2}$$

Comment: Take $ \epsilon=\frac{y-l}{10}$

Comment: If $y<l$, does there exist a real number $z$ with $y<z<l$? The use of Greek $\epsilon $ is nothing but only for intimidation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is correct. You can take any positive $\varepsilon$ less than $y-l$, which is positive. Your argument looks fine to me.